# PHP - preg_match() word after other word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a text like this one: `The cat was born on 1980 and lives ...`

So i want to get the cat's age with regex (the text could have more than 1 occurrence of a number with 4 digits).

I'm trying this `preg_match('/born on [0-9]{4}/', $text, $matches)` but the result is: `array('born on 1980')`. I want to ignore everything before a year.

Demo: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/aYl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the value you want then it will be the first item of the array.

```
$text = 'The cat was born on 1980 and lives ...';
preg_match('/born on ([0-9]{4})/', $text, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Output:

> 1980

Comment: Grouping the value gives an array with 2 items. Any way to get an array only with 1 iteam (the year)?

Comment: The first match is always the entire regex match, and starting in the second array position (element 1)  are any matches made from grouping parentheses. (The above code is correct, but the match of interest is not the first item of the array.)

Comment: The array has two or more values. The first one is everything it found the second and so on is grouped values. Run what i've given you and it should work.

Comment: @idknow if you don't want to get an array, maybe use `preg_replace()` instead ? Something like that `$match = preg_replace('/.*born on ([0-9]{4}).*/', '$1', $text);`